# Only play parts of a YouTube video

Tags: swift, youtube

I am making an app that has a YouTube video view and I was wondering:

Is it possible to only play parts of a YouTube video? Let's say I want the 10 first seconds to play and when it comes to 10 seconds, I would like it to pause.

I would also need to remove the user's ability to interact with the video. I could probably just put an invisible view over the integrated YouTube video, but is there any better way to remove the user's access to the video?

I have looked everywhere for this information, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to insert your own ad during the pause. Please look up Google's terms of use, they may explicitly prohibit doing that.

Comment: If you are using the official iOS YouTube Helper library, look up the docs –
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#control-video-playback